# select current date, if it doesnt exist then look for a future one else take the highest from the past

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data with multipe dates across some rows in a table.
what i want to do is get a date thats currently active if there is no active date then i want to take a future one, if that one also doesnt exist then il take one from the past.

```
table: date_from datetime, date_to datetime, userid varchar
2016-01-01          2016-03-25         Bob
2016-03-26          2016-05-01         Bob
2016-05-02          2016-04-25         Bob

2016-01-01          2016-03-25         Larry
2016-05-02          2016-04-25         Larry

2016-01-01          2016-03-25         Todd
```

For Bob i want to get the date_from value 2016-03-26

While for Larry i want to get 2016-05-02

And Todd 2016-01-01

Here is my sql so far (this also gets the most recent date_from where the date_to from the last row datediff is greater than a variable)

```
    insert into table1 (date_from, resource_id) 
select  date_from, resource_id 
    from 
    (select t.*, row_number() over 
    (partition by resource_id order by 
    (case when datediff(day, prev_date_to, date_from) > $days 
    then 1 else 2 end), date_from ASC ) as seqnum 
        from 
            (select t.*, lag(date_to) over 
            (partition by resource_id order by date_from) as prev_date_to 
            from table2 t  where user = '$user' and date_from <= getdate()
        ) t
    ) t where seqnum = 1
```

I know how to check for the current one and if it doesnt exist get a past one or i can make it get a future one, but i dont understand how to make it check for future dates then go backwards if there are none

Comment: What does `currently active` means? What future one? how does the data looks like? You are missing a lot of information here.

Comment: Try restating your problem in functional terms. You're trying to get some sort of date per user (or resource, you switch halfway) -- why? Given a user (or resource...), what's the algorithm for getting the value if you were not using SQL but an arbitrarily powerful programming language?

Comment: if date_from <= current_date and date_to > current_date
select date_from where date_from <= current_date
elseif date_from > current_date
select min(date_from) where date_from > current_date
else select max(date_from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    date_from DATE,
    date_to DATE,
    userid VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-01-01', '2016-03-25', 'Bob';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-03-26', '2016-05-01', 'Bob';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-05-02', '2016-04-25', 'Bob';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-01-01', '2016-03-25', 'Larry';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-05-02', '2016-04-25', 'Larry';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-01-01', '2016-03-25', 'Todd';

WITH Active AS (
    SELECT * FROM @table WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to),
Latest AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_from DESC) AS row_id FROM @table)
SELECT
    l.userid,
    ISNULL(a.date_from, l.date_from) AS date_from
FROM
    Latest l
    LEFT JOIN Active a ON a.userid = l.userid
WHERE
    l.row_id = 1;
```

Results are:

```
userid  date_from
Bob     2016-03-26
Larry   2016-05-02
Todd    2016-01-01
```

How does it work?  I am just breaking down the problem into two steps, one to find any current records and one to find the latest record for each user.  The logic is then:

- if there is a current record for this user then return the start date of this record;
- if there isn't a current record for this user then return the latest start date for the user.  This will either be in the future or the past.  Because we take the latest date we will prioritise future over past.

This won't work if a user has multiple current records, and I am not sure I fully grasped your meaning of a "current record".

Obviously, if you don't like common table expressions, you could convert this to work with sub queries (as in your example).

Anyway, it might give you a starting point?

---

EDIT

Okay, I just noticed your logic is that you want (in priority order):

- a current record;
- the earliest future record;
- the latest historical record.

This means a few tweaks, so here goes:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    date_from DATE,
    date_to DATE,
    userid VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-01-01', '2016-03-25', 'Bob';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-03-26', '2016-05-01', 'Bob';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-05-02', '2016-04-25', 'Bob';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-01-01', '2016-03-25', 'Larry';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-05-02', '2016-04-25', 'Larry';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '2016-01-01', '2016-03-25', 'Todd';

WITH Active AS (
    SELECT * FROM @table WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN date_from AND date_to),
LatestPast AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_from DESC) AS row_id FROM @table WHERE date_to < GETDATE()),
EarliestFuture AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date_from ASC) AS row_id FROM @table WHERE date_from > GETDATE()),
Users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM @table)
SELECT
    u.userid,
    COALESCE(a.date_from, f.date_from, p.date_from) AS date_from
FROM
    Users u
    LEFT JOIN LatestPast p ON p.userid = u.userid AND p.row_id = 1
    LEFT JOIN EarliestFuture f ON f.userid = u.userid AND f.row_id = 1
    LEFT JOIN Active a ON a.userid = u.userid;
```